# Change string in file from terminal

Tags: command-line, files

So i have this string

> mumbleserver_username: "BOT",

and i want to change BOT to something random without remembering what was before, so no find and replace.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "without remembering what was before"?

Comment: @insert_name_here he doesn't want to do something like : find_position("BOT").

Comment: Still makes no sense to me... Also what is "something random"?

Comment: a random name, doesn't matter, thats why I can't use something like @atayenel said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would almost certainly be possible to hack something together by extracting printable bytes from `/dev/random` (or `/dev/urandom`), `perl` appears to provide at least one module that does exactly what you seem to want:

> ```
> NAME
>
> String::Random - Perl module to generate random strings based on a pattern
> ```

The module is provided in Ubuntu by package `libstring-random-perl`, which you can install via your preferred package manager, or from the command line using `sudo apt install libstring-random-perl` or `sudo apt-get install libstring-random-perl`.

Based on the examples in the [CPAN - String::Random](http://search.cpan.org/~steve/String-Random-0.20/Random.pm) page, you could then do something like:

```
perl -MString::Random=random_string -pe '
  s/\".*\"/sprintf "\"%s\"", random_string("CccnCccn")/e if /mumbleserver_username:/
' yourfile
```

to replace strings between literal double quotes `\".*\"` in lines matching `mumbleserver_username:` by 8-character random strings consisting of a pre-defined mix of upper-case letters `C`, lower-case letters `c`, and digits `n`.

Testing:

```
$ cat file.txt

mumbleserver_username: "BOT",
mumbleserver_username: "foobar",
mumbleserver_username: "NOT",
```

then

```
$ perl -MString::Random=random_string -pe '
    s/\".*\"/sprintf "\"%s\"", random_string("CccnCccn")/e if /mumbleserver_username:/
  ' file.txt

mumbleserver_username: "Wzk1Ihr2",
mumbleserver_username: "Los8Nuz7",
mumbleserver_username: "Sdf8Qmd9",
```

---

To turn the one-liner into a script, you can use the `-MO=Deparse` trick described here: [How can I convert Perl one-liners into complete scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2822721) then paste its output into a file, along with a suitable 'shebang' line like so

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use String::Random (split(/,/, 'random_string', 0));
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/\".*\"/sprintf '"%s"', random_string('CccnCccn');/e if /mumbleserver_username:/;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

Make it executable

```
chmod +x myscript.pl
```

and then you can use it like

```
./myscript.pl yourfile
```

Comment: wow. thanks dude, you are amazing! Can you tell me how to make a executable script ? doesn't seem to work if i make a .pl file and execute it with perl

Comment: @iFEAR I'm not good on actual perl scripts - for stuff like this I tend to cheat and use `-MO=Deparse` as described here: [How can I convert Perl one-liners into complete scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2822721)

Comment: yea .. it seems I can't get it to work, can you tell me at least how to modify the command line script to save to the file ?

Comment: @iFEAR To edit the file in-place (i.e. overwrite the old strings with the random ones), add the `-i` command line option e.g. `perl -i'.bak' ...` (to save a copy of the file with `.bak` suffix) or simply `perl -i ...` (to overwrite without a backup).

Comment: Thank you again, I did it, I put the code in a txt file and execute it by putty. It's not exactly what I wanted, but it does the same thing.